# Accessing data from a .mat file in Python

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, mat

I am trying to use a .mat file from MATLAB in some Python code and I am unsure of how to get the data I want out of it like I can in MATLAB. The code below is how I do it in MATLAB and it results in `N` number of variables in the `CpU` vector and `CpL` vectors such that I can use them in future calculations.

```
N = 1000;
load('Cp.mat')
x_c  = linspace(0,1,N); 

for i = 1:N
   CpU(i) = fnval(Cp_upper, x_c(i));
   CpL(i) = fnval(Cp_lower, x_c(i));
end
```

Below is what I have in Python so far, which loads the .mat file into a dict just fine, but I can't seem to find a way to access the data that I want as I did in MATLAB.

```
import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('Cp.mat')

CpU = mat["Cp_upper"]
```

How can I loop through the dict using `x_c` vector as my input, and output a single `CpU` array that is of length `N`?

Comment: Where do you expect to get `fnval` from?

Comment: We need to know a lot more about your data, variables, functions to be able to help you.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Here's a link to two images that shows what is within the .mat file :[link](http://imgur.com/a/QpSvx). Within it are two 1x1 structs called 'Cp_upper' and 'Cp_lower' each of the same form and the same fields, but with different values under 'knots' and 'coefs', let me know if this helps. I cant seem to find much more about the .mat file apart from this but I can try to upload the file itself if that would make things easier.